# Most appropriate way to graph this data

Tags: r, plot, data-science, pie-chart

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Age    Sex Votes Rating
1  < 18   MALE     7    6.6
2  < 18 FEMALE     1    5.0
3 18-29   MALE  2661    8.7
4 18-29 FEMALE   324    8.6
5 30-44   MALE 11480    8.7
6 30-44 FEMALE  1148    8.6
7   >45   MALE  5543    8.6
8   >45 FEMALE   612    8.5
```

Basically, those are ratings of a movie. I am thinking about what might be the best way to explain all of the information it contains (both the sex distribution and the age one). I think an appropriate way could be plotting some pie-charts, but I would like to hear others opinions.
Thank you a lot in advance!

###### UPDATE

I also have data about the nationality of the voters:

```
  Location Votes Rating
1       US  1847    8.6
2   NON-US 15145    8.6
```

But I think these should be plotted separately, right?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the "best" way - that's very subjective, but you could do a bar plot with one facet for male and one for female. The height of the bars is the rating and its color represents the number of votes.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(factor(Age, unique(Age)), Rating)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Votes)) +
  facet_grid(.~Sex) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15, face = 2),
        panel.spacing = unit(2, "cm")) +
  labs(x = "Age group")
```

[image]

If you want to show countries you could facet by both sex and country:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(factor(Age, unique(Age)), Rating)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Votes)) +
  facet_grid(country~Sex) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15, face = 2),
        panel.spacing = unit(2, "cm")) +
  labs(x = "Age group")
```

### [image]

**Reproducible data from question**

```r
## Without countries
df <- structure(list(Age = c("<18", "<18", "18-29", "18-29", "30-44", 
"30-44", ">45", ">45"), Sex = c("MALE", "FEMALE", "MALE", "FEMALE", 
"MALE", "FEMALE", "MALE", "FEMALE"), Votes = c(7L, 1L, 2661L, 
324L, 11480L, 1148L, 5543L, 612L), Rating = c(6.6, 5, 8.7, 8.6, 
8.7, 8.6, 8.6, 8.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))

## With countries
df <- rbind(df, df)
df$country <- rep(c("USA", "Europe"), each = 8)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you a lot for your help! I consider the first graph to be a very nice solution, I did not think about using the color to demonstrate the number of votes. However, I think something is wrong with the second plot since I don't actually have the data about age and sex per nationality, so basically I think you are plotting the same as the first plot, but twice. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant that you had country data in the same data frame

Comment: Sadly, I don't. This data actually comes from the IMDB api, and for some reason they don't provide that.